# Interpret regression with Heteroskedasticity Corrected Standard Errors in R

Tags: r, multiple-regression, heteroscedasticity, robust-standard-error

In my data I have problems with heteroscedasticity as indicated by the Breusch-Pagan test and the NVC test that are both significant.

Therefore, I would like to follow the method posted by Gavin Simpson here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4385436/regression-with-heteroskedasticity-corrected-standard-errors

I used the one-liner he suggested. This seems to work but now I have troubles interpreting the results as they look very different from my original multiple regression results.

```
mySummary(model_maineffect, vcovHC)

t test of coefficients:

                         Estimate Std. Error  t value  Pr(>|t|)    
(Intercept)             -0.5462588  0.0198430 -27.5291 < 2.2e-16 ***
IV1                      0.0762802  0.0082630   9.2315 < 2.2e-16 ***
Control1                -0.0062260  0.0071657  -0.8689   0.38493    
Control2                 0.0277049  0.0066251   4.1818 2.910e-05 ***
Control3                 0.0199855  0.0104345   1.9153   0.05547 .  
Control4                -0.4639035  0.0083046 -55.8608 < 2.2e-16 ***
Control5                 0.6239948  0.0072652  85.8876 < 2.2e-16 ***

---
Signif. codes:  0 ‘***’ 0.001 ‘**’ 0.01 ‘*’ 0.05 ‘.’ 0.1 ‘ ’ 1

Wald test

Model 1: DV ~ IV1 + Control1 + Control2         + 
    Control3 + Control4 + Control5  
Model 2: DV ~ 1
  Res.Df Df      F    Pr(>F)    
1  14120                        
2  14128 -8 1304.6 < 2.2e-16 ***
---
Signif. codes:  0 ‘***’ 0.001 ‘**’ 0.01 ‘*’ 0.05 ‘.’ 0.1 ‘ ’ 1
```

Can I interpret them just in the same way as a multiple regression, i.e., IV1 has a highly significant effect on DV since Pr(>|t|) of IV1 is <0.001. And does it mean that the model is significantly improved since the Pr(>F) is <0.001? How could I report my R-Square in this case?

Comment: In principle, the test results based on alternative covariance matrices can be interpreted in the same way as usual. If you can give us more context why you believe this is problematic in this situation we might be able to provide more guidance. Re: R-squared. If you believe in heteroscedasticity in the data, then there is no R-squared measure with the same properties as in the homoscedastic case.

Comment: @AchimZeileis: Thanks already, good to know that I can interpret the p-values in the same way. I was concerned the results have to be interpreted differently because there was no R^2 value provided. 

Could I then report my "old R^2" (the one from the regular regression without the alternative covariances)?

Comment: You can do so... but as I said above: If there is heteroscedasticity the R-squared wouldn't have its usual properties.